# How to Join Multiple Columns in Spark SQL using Java for filtering in DataFrame

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

- `DataFrame a` = contains column x,y,z,k
- `DataFrame b` = contains column x,y,a

  ```
  a.join(b,<condition to use in java to use x,y >) ???
  ```

I tried using

```
a.join(b,a.col("x").equalTo(b.col("x")) && a.col("y").equalTo(b.col("y"),"inner")
```

But Java is throwing error saying `&&` is not allowed.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Spark SQL provides a group of methods on `Column` marked as `java_expr_ops`  which are designed for Java interoperability. It includes [`and`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column@and(other:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column) (see also [`or`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column@or(other:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column)) method which can be used here:

```
a.col("x").equalTo(b.col("x")).and(a.col("y").equalTo(b.col("y"))
```

Comment: How to make above condition dynamically using java API in case  of column number is not fixed. For it could be 2, 4, 3,7 or more..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Multiple columns for join, you can do something like this:

```
a.join(b,scalaSeq, joinType)
```

You can store your columns in Java-List and convert List to Scala seq.
Conversion of Java-List to Scala-Seq:

```
scalaSeq = JavaConverters.asScalaIteratorConverter(list.iterator()).asScala().toSeq();
```

Example: `a = a.join(b, scalaSeq, "inner");`

Note: Dynamic columns will be easily supported in this way.