# How to calculate distinct rows frequencies in dataset

Tags: apache-spark

I want to calculate the number of occurences of distinct rows, according to some attributes, and return the results for each distinct row :

I am trying to `groupBy` to get distinct rows according to values of rows in col3 and col4 columns with :

```
dF.select("col0","col1","col2","col3","col4").groupBy("col3","col4")
```

But then how to calculate the occurence of each distinct "grouped" row ?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Are you looking for [count](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46417164/2129801)?

Comment: Yes `agg` and `count` but after grouping each distinct row, because at the end i need to have the count (from the original dataset) of each grouped distinct row. (after rows are grouped the count is 1 for each, but i want the original count while grouping the rows) i hope it is clear

Comment: maybe you could provide some example data (input data and expected output)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You clarifications are not quite clear, but I believe you are trying to add a column to `dF` with the count occurrences of the rows after a `groupBy` based on columns `col3` and `col4`.

Let's say we have the following DataFrame:

```
+----+----+----+-----+----+
|col0|col1|col2| col3|col4|
+----+----+----+-----+----+
|   0|  10| 100|cat26|30.9|
|   1|  20| 200|cat13|22.1|
|   2|  30| 300|cat26|30.9|
|   3|  40| 400|cat26|30.9|
|   4|  50| 500|cat15|15.3|
|   5|  60| 600|cat13|22.1|
+----+----+----+-----+----+
```

First we need to group and aggregate the rows per `col3` and `col4` as [werner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2129801/werner) implied in a `DataFrame` named `grouped`.

```
// Scala
val grouped = dF.select("col0","col1","col2","col3","col4")
          .groupBy("col3","col4")
          .agg(count("*").as("counter"))

// Java
DataFrame grouped = dF.select("col0","col1","col2","col3","col4")
          .groupBy("col3","col4")
          .agg(count("*").as("counter"))
```

`grouped` is going to have this as result:

```
+-----+----+-------+
| col3|col4|counter|
+-----+----+-------+
|cat13|22.1|      2|
|cat26|30.9|      3|
|cat15|15.3|      1|
+-----+----+-------+
```

Then, we must **join** `dF` and `grouped`, using their common columns (`col3`, `col4`) as the keys for the join (`Seq` is a Scala class, but you can load it into Java like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66063203/5644037). If that throws an error, use the workaround seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35212682/5644037)). The `select` method after the join is to preserve the correct queue of the columns, since `join` naturally puts `col3` and `col4` at the start of the schema.

```
// Scala
dF.join(grouped, Seq("col3", "col4"))
  .select("col0","col1","col2","col3","col4", "counter")

// Java
dF.join(grouped, dF.col("col3").equalTo(grouped.col("col3")).and(dF.col("col4").equalTo(grouped.col("col4")))
  .select("col0","col1","col2","col3","col4", "counter")
```

And the output looks like this:

```
+----+----+----+-----+----+-------+
|col0|col1|col2| col3|col4|counter|
+----+----+----+-----+----+-------+
|   0|  10| 100|cat26|30.9|      3|
|   1|  20| 200|cat13|22.1|      2|
|   2|  30| 300|cat26|30.9|      3|
|   3|  40| 400|cat26|30.9|      3|
|   4|  50| 500|cat15|15.3|      1|
|   5|  60| 600|cat13|22.1|      2|
+----+----+----+-----+----+-------+
```

Comment: `dF.join(grouped, Seq("col3", "col4"))
  .select("col0","col1","col2","col3","col4", "counter")` this line is in JAVA ? if not could you provide it in JAVA ?

Comment: Updated with the workaround for Java from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35211993/how-to-join-multiple-columns-in-spark-sql-using-java-for-filtering-in-dataframe/35212682#35212682